# webdriver C# - dropdown selectByVisibleText

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Trying to select a word inside a dropdown menu.

In Webdriver IDE appear this to click the dropdown (which Id is "p" and the to click the word "Barcelona" inside the dropdown.:

[image]

I just can open the dropdown menu using:

```
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("p")).Click();
```

Now I'm trying to select a word inside this dropdown menu, using "selectelement" and "select visibleText" but does not work in C# Webdriver for me.

```
            SelectElement selector = new SelectElement.selectByVisibleText("Barcelona");
```

Any helps please?

Using C# Webdriver and not java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the SelectElement initialization. You can try the following code:

```
SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("p")));
selectElement.SelectByText("Germany");
```

If you are new in the C# WebDriver API, you can find the following article useful: http://automatetheplanet.com/getting-started-webdriver-c-10-minutes/

Comment: Antony, when I want to click to a second dropdownmenu an error says that it is already definied a variable of selectElement, any help please?

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you are using and the most important part of the HTML?

Comment: Using this code (the error of having already the variable selectElement appears when tries to choose the word "January". Here the code: 

         SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Month")));
        selectElement.SelectByText("January");

Comment: I think you need to change the name of the select element for example- monthSelectElement because you have already defined an element with the same name.

Comment: does not work, there is any way to have 2 exact variables in a proyect of selenium with webdriver C#?

Answer (score 0):

In WebDriver.Support.dll Version: 3.1.0 we have SelectElement class.
SelectElement mainly three methods.

Please find the methods:

- To select text we can use **SelectByText**
- To select index we can use **SelectByIndex**
- To select Value we can use **SelectByValue**

Code samples:  **SelectByIndex**

```
SelectElement selectObj = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("year")));
selectObj.SelectByIndex(4);
```

Code samples:  **SelectByText**

```
SelectElement selectObj = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("year")));
selectObj.SelectByText("1990");
```

Code samples:  **SelectByValue**

```
SelectElement selectObj = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("year")));
selectObj.SelectByValue("1990");
```

Please find attached photo for your reference
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6qmH.png)

Further clarification and other methods [Refer](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm)