# How to select a list item from a drop down by its value using Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to select a drop down value. The problem is the drop down list is derived, it is written as list items. Code snippet as follows:

```
<div class="rcbScroll" style="width: 100%; height: 184px; overflow: auto;">
<ul class="rcbList" style="width: 100%">
    <li class="rcbItem">Option 1</li>
    <li class="rcbItem">Option 2</li>
    <li class="rcbItem">Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

How do I select 'Option 2' as the selected value in the drop down?

Comment: Is this a `ul` styled to look like a dropdown? Or did you mean to use an actual `select` element?

Comment: This is a `ul` element styled to look like a drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**using CSS Selectors in Selenium:**

you can get value of nth child by finding it with CSS Selector.

```
// first child: will return "Option 1"
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.rcbList > li:nth-child(1)"));

// second child: will return "Option 2"
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.rcbList > li:nth-child(2)"));

// nth child: will return "Option n"
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.rcbList > li:nth-child(n)"));
```

In case of when `<li>` items are dynamic, then get count and loop over and get all the values.

```
var el_count = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("ul.rcbList"));

for(int index=0; index < el_count.count(); index++){
   // 0 (zero) is the first element in <ul> DOM Array
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul > li:nth-child(index)"));
}
```

**Finding element by Text (value)**

Easier way would be finding by xPath and Class

```
var title = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("./div[@class='aCont']/div/a/span[text() = 'TextToFind']"));
// now title contains text, title = "text to be find"
```

for more [-Example code](https://github.com/kaleemullah360/NaukriGulf.Com/blob/master/NaukriGulf.Com/NaukriGulf_Form.cs)

Comment: Thank you. The first option was sufficient for me.

Comment: With a slight change. driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ul.rcbList > li:nth-child(1)")).Click(); (where I had to specify the class name of the `ul`element)

Comment: Is there a syntax I could follow to select the list item by its value? something along the lines that the list item contains "Option 2"

Comment: Thank you. Your code seems to be correct. so, I ll mark it as the answer. However, the system I'm working with is a bit more complex to automate. Thanks anyway.

Comment: for complex system: 1. get full domain knowledge (not syntax knowledge)
2. python for scrapping
3. R language for scrapping.

Answer (score 0):

try (only if `ul` is treated as dropdown):

```
SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.cssSelector(".rcbList")));
selectElement.SelectByText("Option 2");
```

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31072586/2575259

Comment: Sorry. Didn't work for this scenario. `SelectElement` can only be used for select-option HTML element, not for unordered list items.